# How to remove special characters in a string in Python 3?

Tags: python, string

I would like to convert

from this

```
&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;u&gt;Charming boutique selling trendy casual &amp;amp; dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes &amp;amp; jewelry.&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;
```

to this

```
Charming boutique selling trendy casual dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes jewelry.
```

I'm very confused how to remove not only special characters but also some alphabets between the special characters. Can anyone suggest a way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `html` module and `BeautifulSoup` to get text without escaped tags:

```
s = "&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;u&gt;Charming boutique selling trendy casual &amp;amp; dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes &amp;amp; jewelry.&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import unescape

soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(s), 'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```

Prints:

```
Charming boutique selling trendy casual & dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes & jewelry.
```

Comment: When I checked the source page view, the string shows up with escaped characters, but when I printed it out on the command line, it shows up like this, `<b><i><u>Charming boutique selling trendy casual &amp; dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes &amp; jewelry.</u></i></b>` Your solution removes all the tags, but `$amp;` doesn't get removed. I tried to use `replace` function, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to put the string in meta tag in HTML.

Comment: @Jay you could remove '&' with calling `soup.text.replace('&', '')` in my code.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
import re

string = '&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;u&gt;Charming boutique selling trendy casual &amp;amp; dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes &amp;amp; jewelry.&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;'

string = re.sub('&lt;/?[a-z]+&gt;', '', string)
string = string.replace('&amp;amp;', '&')

print(string)  # prints 'Charming boutique selling trendy casual & dressy apparel for women, some plus sized items, swimwear, shoes & jewelry.'
```

Your string that you want to change looks like it was HTML that's been escaped a few times over, so my solution only works for that kind of thing.

I used regex to replace the tags with empty strings, and also I replaced the escape for an ampersand with a literal `&`.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for, let me know if you have any troubles.