# Cleaning a string with specific type of garbage in the text using python

Tags: python, string, nlp, data-cleaning

I want to extract out the meaningful text out of this string. How to clean this specific type of string.

```
'&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;I booked a flight ticket from Trivandrum to Mumbai&lt;div 
dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;Amount debited from&nbsp;my 
account.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;But 
ticket not received yet.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div 
dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;Please check&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#13;&#10;'
```

Expected Output:

```
I booked a flight from Trivandrum to Mumbai Amount debited from my account. But 
ticket not received yet. Please check

import re
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext

cleanhtml(cleanr)
'&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;I booked a flight ticket from Trivandrum to 
Mumbai&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div 
dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;Amount debited from&nbsp;my account.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div 
dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;But 
ticket not received yet.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div 
dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;Please 
check&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#13;&#10;'
```

String didn't cleaned up, please suggest some solution

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove special characters in a string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601256/how-to-remove-special-characters-in-a-string-in-python-3)